# Programmatically start su session, run command, and remain at root prompt

Tags: shell, zsh, sudo, su

Backstory: I SSH into servers where I want to see a personalized root prompt. However, other people log onto these servers and don't necessarily want me changing the prompt.

Question: How can I make a zsh alias/function such that I can log in as a regular user, and typing `[my su shortcut]` will launch a su session, source .zshrc from my personal home directory, and leave me at a root prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alias mysu="su -c \"ZDOTDIR=$HOME zsh\""
```

See [zsh(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zsh) for details.

Comment: That did what I want! I improved it by prepending ZDOTDIR with `/usr/bin/env ` (that'll help portability if root's normal shell is, say, csh). I also replaced all instances of `~` in .zshrc with `$ZDOTDIR`, and added the following line to the top of .zshrc: `if [ -z "$ZDOTDIR" ]; then ZDOTDIR=$HOME; fi`. Those two changes point zsh to my personal collection of zsh scripts regardless of whether I'm root or my regular user.